# Multi-key combinations to access values in dictionary, python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have Dictionary like this:

```
d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1], (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71]}
```

my target is to get the probability of some special key, for example, I need the probability of `('4', '2'), ('2', '1')`, which is 3/(3+3+1+71)=3/78, but how can I write this method in python?
i have some idea like this:

```
p={}
for i,j in d.keys():
    
    p[i,j]=d[i,j][0]/sum(d[i][0])
```

but it didn't work, because d[I] is not right.

update:
the question has been well solved with some nice answers. Now I want to ask about how to do calculations along a path in a tree that shown in the picture[the picture describes the transitions between states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVHus.png), and I want to find the time needed from every state to the red states.

every path in this tree has two values, for example [6,109.0], 109.0 is the time from ('4','1') to ('1','0'), and on this path, from ('4')->('4','1')->('1','0') is 10.0+109.0=119.0, so the question is how to get the time from current state to the red state?

the transitions between them could be written like this:
states_agg={((), ('2',)): [1, 0.0], (('0', '1'), ('1', '4')): [1, 10.0], (('0', '2'), ('2', '0')): [2, 10.0], (('0', '2'), ('2', '4')): [1, 159.0], (('0', '4'), ('4', '0')): [26, 13.26923076923077],
(('0', '4'), ('4', '2')): [2, 10.5],(('1', '2'), ('2', '4')): [4, 71.5], (('1', '4'), ('4', '1')): [3, 10.333333333333334], (('2',), ('2', '0')): [1, 10.0], (('2', '0'), ('0', '2')): [1, 42.0],
(('2', '0'), ('0', '4')): [6, 109.0], (('2', '1'), ('1', '2')): [3, 43.0], (('2', '3'), ('3', '2')): [1, 860.0],(('2', '4'), ('4', '2')): [76, -223.8815789473684],(('3', '2'), ('2', '0')): [1, 11.0],
(('4', '0'), ('0', '1')): [1, 507.0], (('4', '0'), ('0', '2')): [2, 69.5],(('4', '0'), ('0', '4')): [23, 200.17391304347825],(('4', '1'), ('1', '2')): [1, 95.0],(('4', '1'), ('1', '4')): [2, 1447.0],
(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3, 28.666666666666668] (('4', '2'), ('2', '1'))[3,132.66666666666666], (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1, 64.0],(('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71,79.09859154929578]}

for example from ('4', '2') to ('2', '4') the transition time is 79.09859154929578

Comment: Why is that the probability? I'm not sure I fully understand the logic you are using to get that?

Comment: Isn't the answer to your second question just - `transition_time = states_agg[(('4', '2'), ('2', '4'))][1]`?

Comment: no, transition_time = states_agg[(('4', '2'), ('2', '4'))][1] is only the time from ('4', '2') to  ('2', '4'), i need the transition time from a whole path, for example from the start node('0', '1')to the target node: (('0', '1'), ('1', '4'))->(('4', '1'), ('1', '2'))-> (('2', '0'), ('0', '4')), and ('0', '4') as the target node, the transition time of this path should be added. Is it possible if i name the states end with '4' as target, and find all path to nodes with '4' in this dictionary? and add up transition time of every single path ?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are choosing that path? From your graph it looks like I could just go (0,1) --> (1,4) --> (4,0). Besides this, I think your operations may now be getting a little complicated for this dictionary structure and key structure. I don't know a huge amount about networks in python but you might look at something like [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#) which seems like it might fit your use case

Comment: thanks, it seems so, : )

Comment: Excuse me, I have a new question, could you please take a look and maybe help out with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706259/find-chains-in-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648064/6529697) by CDJB may be what you are after.

However if your dictionary ever has keys in it for which you don't wish to use in calculating the probability (which your `d[i]` seems to imply) you will need to make some tweaks:

```
def get_prob_from_key(mykey, dikt):
    numer = dikt.get(mykey)
    if numer is None:
        print(f"Key {mykey} not found! Can't calculate probability")
        return None
    denom = sum(v[0] for k, v in d.items() if mykey[0] == k[0])
    return numer[0]/denom

d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1], (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71], (('4', '1'), ('1', '2')): [1], (('4', '1'), ('1', '4')): [2],}

k1 = (('4', '2'), ('2', '1'))
k2 = (('4', '2'), ('2', '4'))
k3 = (('5', '2'), ('2', '1'))
k4 = (('4', '1'), ('1', '2'))

get_prob_from_key(k1, d)
> 0.038461538461538464

get_prob_from_key(k2, d)
> 0.9102564102564102

get_prob_from_key(k3, d)
> Key (('5', '2'), ('2', '1')) not found! Can't calculate probability

get_prob_from_key(k4, d)
> 0.3333333333333333
```

A caveat:

This assumes that, like your current dictionary input, all values are lists of length 1. If that's not always the case then a change will need to be made.

Comment: thanks so much, I never thought that this web could be so helpful, I should come to this earlier: )

Comment: is that possible that I add an extra key to the dictionary (('0', '2'), ('2', '0')): [2, 10.0], so d looks like this now d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1], (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71], (('0', '2'), ('2', '0')): [2, 10.0]} , and I want the probability of this new added single element is 0? from the get_prob_from_key method, the probability of this new added should be 1. But I this element is considered as a safe one, all other transitions are critical

Comment: Can you be clearer please? Do you want the function to output `0` for the key ` (('0', '2'), ('2', '0'))`? What is the logic for that, and it has 2 elements in it's value list, why is this and how does that affect other cases? Perhaps you could provide more context for this problem, like what is generating these values?

Comment: for my case, the tuple begins with ('4', '2') are critical states, the tuple begin with other things are all safe states, for all safe state I want the output for them with '0', for the critical states it's meaningful to calculate the probability, but for safe states we can simply say the output is '0'

Comment: I’m still not entirely clear here. If you want anything that isn’t (4,2) to be 0 then you just need to call the function on keys starting with that? And set anything else to 0?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like the following?

```
d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71]}

s = sum(v[0] for v in d.values())

p = {k: v[0]/s for k, v in d.items()}
```

This gives us:

```
>>> p
{(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): 0.038461538461538464,
 (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): 0.038461538461538464,
 (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): 0.01282051282051282,
 (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): 0.9102564102564102}
```

Answering question from comments - how can I get the probability of keys begin with ('4', '1') with `d` as below:

```
d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3], (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1], (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71], (('4', '1'), ('1', '2')): [1], (('4', '1'), ('1', '4')): [2],}
```

Then we can just use a list comprehension on `p`:

```
>>> [v for k, v in p.items() if k[0] == ('4', '1')]
[0.012345679012345678, 0.024691358024691357]
```

And if we want the total probability of those keys:

```
>>> sum(v for k, v in p.items() if k[0] == ('4', '1'))
0.037037037037037035
```

Comment: thanks, that is fast what I want. but if the dictionary is like this: d={(('4', '2'), ('2', '0')): [3],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '1')): [3],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '3')): [1],
   (('4', '2'), ('2', '4')): [71], (('4', '1'), ('1', '2')): [1],
 (('4', '1'), ('1', '4')): [2],}, how can I get the probability of keys begin with ('4', '1'),?

Comment: The function in my answer may help with that.

Comment: thanks to all of you, maybe i am not very clear in my comment, I need the probability of every element that begins with the same tuple, for example: probability of (('4', '1'), ('1', '2')) is 1/(1+2); probability of ('4', '2'), ('2', '1'), which is 3/(3+3+1+71)=3/78, the calculation of the probability that starts with different tuple should be calculated separately

Comment: is that possible that I add an extra key to the dictionary :